# Unable to upload data using sagemaker_session.upload_data in s3 bucket that I created, it is getting stored in default s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

So I am trying iris to get acquainted with was sagemaker I am following simple tutorials from [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/training-and-deploying-custom-tensorflow-models-with-aws-sagemaker-72027722ad76). I have created a bucket named "tf-practise-iris-data" and gave the IAM role of Sagemaker access to the s3 bucket as mentioned in the tutorial. I also tried creating a new bucket with a different name thinking there might be some problem with a bucket but still it is having the same issue, this is the snippet of my code [image]. And I have turned off Block all public access from the bucket but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
prefix = "checking-with-new-bucket"
training_input_path = sagemaker_session.upload_data('train.csv', bucket = 'checking-with-new-bucket',key_prefix = prefix + "/training")
training_input_path
```

Which gave output as

```
's3://checking-with-new-bucket/checking-with-new-bucket/training/train.csv'
```